# How to implement (fast) bigint division?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, biginteger, integer-division

I'm currently making my own BigInt class, by splitting numbers by 7 digits. (i.e. in base 10,000,000)

I implemented addition, subtraction, and multiplication, and now I'm implementing division and mod. I wrote a code that performs division by long division (estimating numbers by dividing most-significant digits), and it works.

However, it is too slow. When I test operations on a 108-digit number and a 67-digit number, it takes 1.9ms to calculate division, much slower than other operations (0.007~0.008ms to calculate addition/subtraction, 0.1ms to calculate multiplication).

Like Karatsuba and FFT algorithm for fast multiplication, what algorithms exist for calculating division? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(digital)) demonstrates some division algorithm (which calculates multiplicative inverse of divisor and multiplies it with dividend), but I think that doesn't help me much implementing division. I read the 'Large Integer Methods' sections too but that doesn't help me neither... :(

Comment: Good question, but you might consider http://programmers.stackexchange.com instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: Simple google search demonstrates tones of article about this, I don't think it's easy work, but the main Idea is use fast multiplication, and all the algorithms are around this. e.g you can take a look at [fast division in large integers](http://www.treskal.com/kalle/exjobb/original-report.pdf)

Comment: Any chance you could open source this? There isn't currently a good bigint library for JS.

Answer (score 3):

The standard reference for big-integer arithmetic is Donald Knuth's book *Art of Computer Programming*, Volume 2, Section 4.3. His division algorithm is basically the grade-school algorithm, with some small improvements.

By the way, [most people](http://programmingpraxis.com/2011/05/24/big-numbers-getting-started/) that implement big-integer arithmetic use a power of two rather than a power of ten as the radix of their number system.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you have a look at the source code of the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/) and port the functionality you need to JavaScript, or get an idea of how it's done.

If there is a good algorithm out there, this library will most likely have it; and it is distributed under the LGPL.

Comment: You can also use the LLVM -> javascript (emscripten) compiler to automatically port the entire library

Comment: @Raynos I wouldn't bet on the output of emscripten being callable from JS without major pain, and especially not across emscription versions.

Comment: I read some codes (`divexact.c` and `divegcd.c`), and it seems that bitwise operations are included, which I can't implement (because I'm representing numbers in base 10^7)...

Answer (score 2):

For a reasonably fast division algorithm, look at http://myweb.lmu.edu/dmsmith/MComp1996.pdf

It is still O(n^2) but efficient for moderate lengths. It is especially well suited when you are using bases that are smaller than the word size. Years ago, I implemented it in Python. The code is buried in http://home.comcast.net/~casevh/decint_041.tar.gz . Look for the functions smithdiv() and remainder_norm().